# React 17 jsx transform with hooks

Tags: reactjs

With the new JSX transform that dropped in React 17, we don't need to write import react from 'react'.
But
If I'm using hooks, I'd anyway be doing, say, import { useState } from 'react' which would include react anyway.

So, is there a benefit of omitting import react from 'react'?
Will it reduce bundle size in this case?

Comment: No, there is no benefit, its just a babel transform https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Comment: If they are claiming that's gonna reduce bundle size with jsx transform, will it actually be reduced if I'm using hooks since react would anyway be imported?

Comment: Usually you import whole react and it is poorly tree shaken. With new transform you import only what you really need. I might be mistaken here, but this is how it feels.